# Read in data from same subfolder in different subfolders to R

Tags: r, loops

I have multiple folders in my data file such that the files all have a common directory of "~/Desktop/Data/". Each file in the data folder is different such that

```
/Desktop
  /Data
    /File1/Data1/
    /File2/Data1/
    /File3/Data1/
```

The `File` folders are different but they all contain a data folder that is named the same. I have `.dta` files in each of the data subfolders that I would like to read into R

EDIT: I should also note the contents in the `File` folders to be:

```
../Filex
    /Data1 -- What I want to read from
    /Data2
    /Data3
    /Code
```

with `/Filex/Data1` being the main folder of interest. All `File` folders are structured this way.

I have consulted multiple stack overflow feeds and so far only figured out how to list them all had all the `File` folders been the same. However, I am unsure as to how I can read the data into R if these `File` folders were named slightly differently.

I have tried this thus far, but I get an empty set in return

```
files <- dir("~/Desktop/Data/*/Data/", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, pattern="\\.dta$")
```

For actual data, downloading files from ICPSR might help in replicating the issue.

EDIT: I am working on MAC OSX 10.15.5

Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: Are all folders in `Data` of the structure `/Filex/Data/` or are there also other folders?

Comment: All of them have that structure, yes. There is nothing else there. Thank you!

Within the /Filex folder, there are other things that are not of interest -- example: code files, codebooks, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
files <- dir("~/Desktop/Data",pattern=".+.dta$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
# to make sure /Data is there, as suggestted by @Martin Gal:
files[grepl("Data/",files)]
```

This [Regex tester](https://spannbaueradam.shinyapps.io/r_regex_tester/) and this [Regex cheatsheet](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf) have been very useful to come to the solution.

Tested under Windows :

```
files <- dir('c:/temp',pattern=".+.dta$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
files[grepl("Data/",files)]   
[1] "c:/temp/File1/Data/test2.dta" "c:/temp/File2/Data/test.dta"
```

Comment: This works here nicely, however it would also return `.dta` files that are directly in the upper `Data` folder. I wonder if there is a possibility to use wildcards in paths in `R`

Comment: Perhaps subsetting further with `files[grep("Data/File\\d+/Data1/", files)]` is useful.

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating how this might fit into the above answer? I cannot seem to get this to work. The above answer also doesn't work for me, but I think it is worth a shot.

Comment: Edited a better answer : got Data, still fighting with special character /